# AllPoetry management

Tags: community

Who owns All Poetry, and do they make a profit from it?

I like the community basis, but I'm leery of giving rights to my IP to a website if I don't know much about how it's used.

Comment: Please provide a link and explain what "giving rights to my IP" means.

Comment: IP here is 'intellectual property', which I assume this site claims over material posted there.

Comment: "giving rights to my IP" means ceding some sort of publishing or distribution rights to creative content (intellectual property) that's posted on a third party website.  There's almost always some sort of ceding of IP rights in that situation, as otherwise the website wouldn't be able to include it on web pages!

Comment: You give usage writes, but not ownership rights, to your IP. Their terms are the same as Facebook's in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick read of the [website](http://allpoetry.com/) I can see that members can pay a subscription for additional services, so they do make money. All Poetry is a legal entity, so it's that entity that makes the money.

Their Ts&Cs state that you retain ownership of all content, they gain a non-exclusive license to publish your content on their site.

> **Ownership of content**
>  You maintain ownership and copyright to your poetry, poems, or other original works of art you upload to our
>   sites, including the right to publish it elsewhere. By uploading your
>   digital content, you are granting us the nonexclusive right to display
>   that material on the internet. Displaying your material to others on
>   the internet is a form of publication, and as such you grant us the
>   rights to republish it to each visitor's browser[...]

Comment: That's relevant, but tangential to my question.  I was more concerned with the group who owns the site, and if their money coming in greatly exceeds the cost of running the website.

Comment: @AdamMiller, they're a company, their goal is to make money. Perhaps if you explained why this is a problem?

Comment: Did I say there was a problem?

Comment: @AdamMiller. If there's not then why ask the question?